# How can I edit coordinates on a map imported from a delimited text layer?

Tags: csv, dictionary, coordinates, qgis

I have a .shp and a .csv with coordinates. I want to plot those coordinates on the map. However, some points are out of my desired range and I want to delete them. I know I can't edit the layer but what are my options? Plot every single coordinate and delete them in the csv and then upload it?

Answer (score 0):

Using QGIS, I would do as follows:

1. Load the shapefile, and the CSV (delimited text).
2. Save the CSV points as a layer (geopackage or shapefile)
3. Use the "Select by Location" tool (Under Vector->Research Tools), and choose the "disjoint" predicate (points originally from CSV **not in** shapefile areas).
4. Begin editing the points layer, and click the "Delete Selected" button to delete all selected (those outside the shapefile areas).
5. Save edits
6. If you need this as a CSV, use the "Save as" option on that layer.